# KVL makes no sense

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

So here's the deal. I've looked at DC circuits, and I see the KCL clearly. Current buildup is rare, so the the KCL (Kirchoff Current Law) makes plenty enough sense. The KVL, on the other hand, makes little to no sense. What goes up must come down. True, but what does that mean in application to an actual circuit, given an applied potential difference? Please explain the KVL: I need help.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you don't understand?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand why the components are assigned voltages and that these such voltages, summed with the source, equal zero.

Comment: Why doesn't just the battery have a voltage-do you see what I mean?

Comment: Think of it like a series of staircases. You start at ground level or zero potential.  You increase your potential by walking up stairs, and decrease it by walking down.  But when you get to the same level you started at, your potential is back to zero.

Comment: Thanks John D. So you're saying that an electron that starts its journey in a simple wire-battery set up will, after going through the loop, eventually stop? If true, what about ac current? The electrons never stop moving so how do they complete their wire journey?

Comment: @user162549, John D isn't remotely implying that an "electron will stop".  How did you conclude that from his comment?

Comment: So if an electron is given energy due to a potential difference, this energy in a closed loop is unsustainable due to a finite loop, and so will stop. Energy in=energy out. Uh oh. I may be interpreting differently though? Be aware that I am new haha. @AlfredCentauri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think of a battery (or other voltage source) as a "provider" of voltage, and all the components of a circuit as "consumers" of the voltage, then logically all the voltage provided by the battery must be consumed by the components.  You can't have voltage left over as it would have nowhere to be.

It's like having a 3-pint jug of beer and three pint glasses.  All the beer goes from the jug into the pint glasses.  If you had a 4-pint jug you'd end up with beer all over the floor.  If you only had a 2-pint jug you'd have annoyed friends.

So, what gets provided must be consumed exactly - ergo the sum of all voltages (battery is +, components are -) must equal 0 (+3 pints -1 pint -1 pint -1 pint = 0 pints spilled and 0 annoyed friends).

Answer (score 1):

I think of Kirchoff's laws as scientific wording of (what should be) common-sense observations.

In this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpvqDA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

with a 9 volt battery, and 300 ohms total resistance, Ohm's Law says we have a current of 30 mA.  This current will result in 3 volts being developed (or dropped) across each resistor.

The 3 volts across each resistor totals 9 volts - exactly the battery voltage!

If we had, say, 2.9 volts across the R3, we would have 0.1 volts between the bottom of R3 and the negative battery terminal.  However, those points are connected by a theoretical wire, which has no resistance (zero ohms).  With 0.1 volts across 0 ohms, we will have infinite current in the bottom wire, which can't happen (Kirchoff says so, in the Current Law), so the voltages around this loop must add to zero.

Comment: Ah so pressures (voltages) are additive. Appreciate the help. I seem to have infinite questions yet I need help answering them, so thank you

Comment: @user162549, voltages of components **in series** are additive.

Comment: Understood, parallel components effectively decrease resistance

Answer (score 0):

KCL: Based on conservation of charge

KVL: Based on conservation of energy

(*This to be simple - no line integrals or Maxwell's treatment...*).

Comment: Cool, conservation of charge. I agree that conservation of energy is a thing too. But I don't get why the KVL applies to conservation of energy. If I see a battery and a resistor in a circuit, I see that a potential difference is applied and causes current to flow. I see that energy is applied. Where does this energy conservation come into my simple circuit? Just curious. Thank you

Comment: 1 Volt = 1 Joule/Coulomb (work or energy change per charge unit). For a 10 V battery, the work done by the electric force (on electric filed) in moving 1 Coulomb (charge corresponding to 6.241e+18 electrons) from negative lead to the positive one is 10 Joules - distributed between the loads (resistance) along the closed path or circuit.

Comment: @user162549, i.e. the power (energy) dissipated by all the components in the system must equal the energy supplied to that circuit by the source. Power supplied = Power dissipated.

Answer (score 0):

KVL means that all voltage drops in a circuit (same loop) will add up to the source voltage for the loop. You can think of the source voltage as a positive voltage and any voltage drops across components as a negative voltage. For example, if you have a 5 volt battery hooked up to a resistor, you know that resistor is getting all of the voltage (where else will it go?). As such this would be, Vb-Vr=0 volts, or, 5 + (-5) = 0 volts. KVL is a conservation of energy within a loop.

Comment: Weird. Why does the component get a voltage?

Comment: Ohm's Law says that if a current flows through a resistance, a voltage will be developed across that resistance.

Comment: I know the battery has a voltage, but why does a resistor have another voltage. That's two voltages, but only one electric field. Thanks

Comment: @user162549, between the negative and positive terminal of the battery there exists a 9V, in this case, potential difference. By placing components across the leads of your battery you are directing an electric field through each component and thereby inducing a current. The voltage across the resistors is not generated in combination to the supply, but rather generated *from* the supply as the current through the resistors dissipates energy as heat and progressively subtracts from the peak potential.

Answer (score 0):

The algebraic sum of all the voltages in a closed loop must equal zero. The laws of physics are not just good ideas. Imagine what Kirchhoff must have gone through to come up with this law before the law even existed. Another way of looking at your question is to imagine a thought experiment where you travel around the world and stop where you started months or years later and you are asked, how far have you moved? Keep in mind that you are at the very same spot you were when you started. As you traveled you went down one side of the globe and up the other to end up in the same spot you started. The sum of all distances and directions in your travel around the world must equal to zero.